# How can I define the minimum and maximum version of Android to publishing the app in Cordova using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android, cordova

I have developed an app in Cordova. Now going to publish this on Play Store. But before publishing, I want to know how can define the Minimum and maximum version of Android while building the APK file in Cordova using Visual Studio.

Or there will be another setting for minimum and maximum version of Android on play store?

Any suggestion will be appreciable.
Thank You!!

Answer (score 1):

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"
          android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
          android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

Documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

Related info [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html#how)

Answer (score 0):

Use `config.xml` file from the below directroy

```
app/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml
```

Very simple

Comment: Reached to the file, now what to do with this file?
Can you please explain with an example?